# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle delete token and jwt token of an user by his id

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

is there any way to delete the token of an user only by his id or username in LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle
in Symfony 6 ?

expected to redirect the user to logout whilte his logged in

Comment: Do you find solution ?